# Change css site-wide on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I'm trying to do is display two different menus based on an option that is selected. 
In my snippet you can see I have `option a` and `option b`

```css
.option-a, .option-b {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.option-a:hover, .option-b:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.option-a-content {
  display: block;
}
.option-b-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="option-a">
Option A
</div>
<div class="option-b">
Option B
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="option-a-content">
This is the contents of A
</div>
```

`option-a-content` is set to `display: block` and `option-b-content` is set to `display: none;`

I want to make it so when you click 'Option B' it changes the css of `option-a-content` to `display: none` and it to `display: block`

Edit: for clarification, my issue is that I can get the css to change on click, however when I navigate away from the page, it reverts back to default.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Oh sorry, my problem specifically is that when using the jquery css function, I cannot get it to stay that way when I navigate between pages, so I can get it to enable/disable either div, but when I navigate away from the page I did it on, it resets back to default

Comment: You need to remember the state, either client-side with localstorage or server-side with session variables (for example). Depending on which solution you choose, your app would have to find out what state the content was supposed to be in and then update it accordingly. Since you're using JavaScript on the page anyway I'd suggest that you look to store the user's choice in localstorage and retrieve it on documentReady. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of storing the state in localstorage:

```
$(function(){
    $(".option-toggle").on("click", function(){
        //get the href of the clicked item. This is the id of the element we wish to show
        var selectedOptionID=$(this).attr("href");
        //hide all option-content elements
        $(".option-content").attr("aria-hidden",true);
        //show the one we want
        $(selectedOptionID).attr("aria-hidden",false);
        //remember the active one in localstorage 
        localStorage.setItem("selectedOptionID", selectedOptionID);
    });

    //onload, read from local storage and trigger a click on the appropriate option:
    var selectedOptionIdFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("selectedOptionID");
    if(selectedOptionIdFromStorage){
        //trigger a click on the select-option having a href equal to selectedOptionIdFromStorage:
        $(".option-toggle[href='"+selectedOptionIdFromStorage+"']").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jvsnphmn/3/

Comment: I would have put this in a snippet but it wont work due to localstorage restrictions.